# Apply scale on ongoing CSS animated bitmap?

Tags: css, bitmap

I have a bitmap with an applied animation style that spins it ad nausaum. I would like it to move to the left and resize about 50% when an event is triggered (hover in this case). I've been able to apply smoothly the movement towards the left, but i get no response with the transform: scale command. [See jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/80y1dmtz/).

```
.wheel:hover {
    margin-left: -228px;
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't work because you have `transform:rotate()` on the image from the animation. and adding another `transform` on the same image, in the same time the animation is working, it's not possible

instead of `transform:scale(0.5)` you can use `height:50%;width:auto` . see snippet below or fiddle > **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80y1dmtz/1/)**

let me know if it helps

```css
@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

.wheel {
 position: fixed; 
 top: 30px;
 left: 140px; 
 animation: spin 15s infinite linear;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.wheel:hover {
 margin-left: -228px;
 width:auto;
 height:50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/616542814319415296/McCTpH_E.jpg" class="wheel">
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Sadly the smooth transition as in the scale method is lost. Strange thing is that setting height to "50%" in firefox actually *doubles* the picture size. Setting it to 35% does the job. Many thanks.

Comment: @pacotanaka glad i could help. don't forget to rate my answer as accepted :D